# Let $y$ be a column vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and $S=\{Ay \mid A \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\}$. Show that $S$ is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $y$ be a column vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and $S=\{Ay \mid A \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\}$, where $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ denotes the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries.
Show that $S$ is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$.

**Attempt:**
Denote $\mathbf{0^{1n}}$ and $\mathbf{0_M}$ be the zero column vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and the zero matrix in $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$, respectively.

1. Since $\mathbf{0_M} \cdot \mathbf{0^{1n}} =\mathbf{0^{1n}} \in S$, then $S \ne \emptyset$.
2. Let $u=Ay, v=By \in S$. Then,
   \begin{align*}
   u+v &= Ay+By \\
   &= 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a_{11}y_{11} + a_{12}y_{12} + \ldots + a_{1n}y_{1n} \\
   a_{21}y_{21} + a_{22}y_{22} + \ldots + a_{2n}y_{2n} \\
   \ldots \\
   a_{n1}y_{n1} + a_{n2}y_{n2} + \ldots + a_{nn}y_{nn}
   \end{bmatrix} + 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   b_{11}y_{11} + b_{12}y_{12} + \ldots + b_{1n}y_{1n} \\
   b_{21}y_{21} + b_{22}y_{22} + \ldots + b_{2n}y_{2n} \\
   \ldots \\
   b_{n1}y_{n1} + b_{n2}y_{n2} + \ldots + b_{nn}y_{nn}
   \end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   (a_{11}+b_{11})y_{11} + (a_{12}+b_{12})y_{12} + \ldots + 
   (a_{1n}+b_{12})y_{1n} \\
   (a_{21}+b_{21})y_{21} + (a_{22}+b_{22})y_{22} + \ldots + 
   (a_{2n}+b_{2n})y_{2n} \\
   \ldots \\
   (a_{n1}+b_{n1})y_{n1} + (a_{n2}+b_{n2})y_{n2} + \ldots + 
   (a_{nn}+b_{nn})y_{nn}
   \end{bmatrix} \\
   &= (A+B)y \in S.
   \end{align*}
3. Let $k \in \Bbb R$. Then, for all
   $Ay \in S$,
   \begin{align*}
   k\cdot (Ay) = kAy = (kA)y \in S.
   \end{align*}
   Hence, by the subspace criteria, $S$ is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$.

Am I true?

Comment: Note that $S$ as you have described it is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, not $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: yes, your reasoning is correct. I posted an answer, but it where downvoted, meaning that the community disliked my answer. So, I post a comment. Anyway: Yes, your reasoning is coorect.

Comment: Okay, thanks!..

Comment: Does there a typo? Does it mean $M_{n\times 1}(\Bbb R)$? Not $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: If you have copied the question correctly, then yes there is definitely a typo

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have copied the question correctly, that is, it written as $n×n$, not $n×1$.

Comment: ok, if it is $n\times n$ then S is jut not a subset of the $n\times n$ matrices. If we assume a typo, i.e. the question is if $S$ is a subspace of the set of matrices $n\times 1$ (where it lives) then the reasoning is correct, and $S$ is indeed a subspace.